# Does iCloud upload all files in the Documents directory to the cloud servers?

Tags: ios, file, icloud, universal, uidocument

I was under the impression that iCloud only worked with UIDocument files.
How about other types?

Also if my user's files get uploaded into the cloud, can he use those files with all his devices if my app is universal?

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple's [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html),

> Handle support files—files your application downloads or generates and
>   can recreate as needed—in one of two ways:
>
> 1. In iOS 5.0 and earlier, put support files in the
>      /Library/Caches directory to prevent them from
>      being backed up
> 2. In iOS 5.0.1 and later, put support files in the
>      /Library/Application Support directory and apply
>      the com.apple.MobileBackup extended attribute to them. This
>      attribute prevents the files from being backed up to iTunes or
>      iCloud. If you have a large number of support files, you may store
>      them in a custom subdirectory and apply the extended attribute to
>      just the directory.

iCloud does back up of the things under Library also.

Ans YES of course if user's files get uploaded into the cloud, then he can use those files with all his devices if the app is universal as iCloud is intended to be the invisible magic that glues your iPhone, iPad and Mac (if you use one) together.